# How to generate layered pdf file using PdfBox?

Tags: java, pdf, layer, pdfbox

I have a problem with generating a layered pdf page using PdfBox. I have seen several posts here on the subject, but they focus on importing pages from another pdf to a target document.

My case is a liitle bit different (at least I think so :) ).
I created a class MapImage that contains the paper size (in pixels) and a list of BufferedImages' that I want to add to a single pdf page.

Here is the code that I tried:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
for (MapImage image : images) {
    PDPage page = new PDPage(new PDRectangle(image.getPaperWidth(), image.getPaperHeight()));
    page.setResources(new PDResources(new COSDictionary()));
    document.addPage(page);

    LayerUtility layerUtility = new LayerUtility(document);
    int i=1;
    for(BufferedImage layer : image.getLayers()) {
        PDJpeg img = new PDJpeg(document, layer);                        
        layerUtility.appendFormAsLayer(page, new PDXObjectForm(img.getCOSStream()), new AffineTransform(), "Layer " + i++);
    }
}
document.save(baos);
document.close();
```

Unfortunately the resulting PDF is corrupted.
I manged to create a page with only one image (with no layers) but unfortunately I have no idea how to do this.

Did anyone have come accross such problem ?

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to use optional content groups (aka layers) at all?

Comment: Yes. I was supposed to prepare a pdf file that contains the map data. The map is made of many different layers. Sometimes it is essential for the person that receives the PDF to be able to turn off some layers to see what is below them.

Comment: Ah, ok, that wasn't clear from the original question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, I solved it.
This is the method that does what I wanted. Maybe it will be useful for someone :)

```
public static PDOptionalContentGroup appendImageAsLayer(PDDocument document, PDPage targetPage, BufferedImage image, String layerName) throws IOException {
    PDDocumentCatalog catalog = document.getDocumentCatalog();
    PDOptionalContentProperties ocprops = catalog.getOCProperties();
    if (ocprops == null) {
        ocprops = new PDOptionalContentProperties();
        catalog.setOCProperties(ocprops);
    }
    if (ocprops.hasGroup(layerName)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Optional group (layer) already exists: " + layerName);
    }

    PDOptionalContentGroup layer = new PDOptionalContentGroup(layerName);
    ocprops.addGroup(layer);

    PDResources resources = targetPage.findResources();
    if(resources == null ) {
        resources = new PDResources(new COSDictionary());
        targetPage.setResources(resources);
    }
    PDPropertyList props = resources.getProperties();
    if (props == null) {
        props = new PDPropertyList();
        resources.setProperties(props);
    }

    // Find first free resource name with the pattern "MC<index>"
    int index = 0;
    PDOptionalContentGroup ocg;
    COSName resourceName;
    do {
        resourceName = COSName.getPDFName("MC" + index);
        ocg = props.getOptionalContentGroup(resourceName);
        index++;
    } while (ocg != null);
    // Put mapping for our new layer/OCG
    props.putMapping(resourceName, layer);
    PDJpeg img = new PDJpeg(document, image);

    PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, targetPage, true, false);
    contentStream.beginMarkedContentSequence(COSName.OC, resourceName);
    contentStream.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    contentStream.endMarkedContentSequence();
    contentStream.close();

    return layer;
}
```

Comment: what does "MC"+index denote?

Comment: Honestly speaking - I have no idea. I came up with this solution using pieces of code I found on the net. I suppose this is some kind of a resource naming convention that is being recognized by the pdf viewers. I am not a pdf expert and unfortunately I did not have time to look more deeply into it. But I would also like to hear an answer to your question.

Comment: MC probably stands for Marked Content

Answer (score 1):

For PDFBox 2.0:

```
public static PDOptionalContentGroup appendImageAsLayer(PDDocument doc, PDPage page,
                                                        PDImageXObject pdImage, AffineTransform transform,
                                                        String layerName) throws IOException {
    PDDocumentCatalog catalog = doc.getDocumentCatalog();
    PDOptionalContentProperties ocprops = catalog.getOCProperties();
    if (ocprops == null) {
        ocprops = new PDOptionalContentProperties();
        catalog.setOCProperties(ocprops);
    }
    PDOptionalContentGroup layer = ocprops.getGroup(layerName);
    if (layer == null) {
        layer = new PDOptionalContentGroup(layerName);
        ocprops.addGroup(layer);
    }

    try (PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(
            doc, page, PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND, false)) {
        contentStream.beginMarkedContent(COSName.OC, layer);
        contentStream.saveGraphicsState();
        contentStream.transform(new Matrix(transform));
        contentStream.drawImage(pdImage, 0, 0, pdImage.getWidth(), pdImage.getHeight());
        contentStream.restoreGraphicsState();
        contentStream.endMarkedContent();
    }

    return layer;
}
```

PDImageXObject can be created using:

```
PDImageXObject pdImage = PDImageXObject.createFromFile(imagePath, doc);
```